# different results with MEKA vs Scikit-learn!

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, accuracy, weka

I have a multilabel data which I've trained using different classifiers with **MEKA** (multilabel version of **WEKA**) and the evaluation results (e.g. accuracy) that **MEKA** gives me are different from those I get from the same classifiers of **scikit-learn**.

I am using Binary Relevance method (which is both in MEKA and scikit-multilearn), because of my data being multilabel. And for instance, I am using SVM which is *SMO* in MEKA (and WEKA) and *linearSVC* in sklearn.

Now the accuracy I get from *10-fold cross-validation* with *BR>SMO* in MEKA is about **50%** where I get something around **20%** accuracy from *BinaryRelevanvce>LinearSVC*. Other evaluation measures (e.g. f1-score, hamming loss etc.) don't match as well.

I tried to give all the parameters I could find in the input of *LinearSVC*, the same value as those of *SMO* but there's no luck. My Python code would be like this:

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

my_classifier = BinaryRelevance(
                classifier=LinearSVC(C=1, random_state=1, tol=0.001, max_iter=10000, dual=False),
                require_dense=[True, True])
```

I must add that using *BR>SMO* in MEKA to train and evaluate the model would take almost **an hour** on my data, but sklearn's *linearSVC* (with skmultilern's *BinaryRelevance*) takes less than **10 minutes** on the same data (hence the lower accuracy).

And by the way, I'm using `accuracy_score` method in `sklearn.metrics` for accuracy.

So my question is what am I missing? How can I get the same accuracy from **SVM** in **MEKA** and **scikit-learn**?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843981/under-what-parameters-are-svc-and-linearsvc-in-scikit-learn-equivalent)

> LinearSVC is not linear SVM, do not use it if do not have to.

and furthermore

> LinearSVC [is] one of the mistakes of sklearn developers.

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaX5M.png) from the question you can observe how it is inaccurate, even compared to SVC with kernel=linear.

Further differences may be explained with differences how SMO and SVC with linear kernel are implemented.

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130293/svm-and-smo-main-differences) compare the two, and the answer is SMO should be the fastest one, otherwise your dataset maybe is not suitable for it.

I would test SVC with linear kernel and see if things change.